# Dagger 2 context based scope

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am working on a relatively complex framework with `Activities`, `Services`, and `ContentProviders`.

I need to have access to an instance Foo but that instance needs to be the same at a defined scope. -> For example, I have class `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

`A` would spawn `B`, `C`, and `A`,`B`,`C` will use the same instance of `Foo`

`D` would spawn another `B`, `C`, that `D`,`B`,`C` will also use another instance of `Foo`.

How do I structure my component and modules so each Context only has one instance of Foo, but multiple context would not share the Foo instance?

Right now I only have a Component created that has several modules and each class would call

`DaggerComponent.getComponent().inject(this);`

and I am having trouble wrapping my head around solving this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "multiple context " what are you referring to?

Comment: You call it a "Singleton", and claim you have "an instance", but then allude to one instance _per_ Activity, Service, or ContentProvider. Is it one instance across the whole app, or one instance per object?

Comment: Apologize if I didn't make it clear. I would say it's a singleton based on my defined scope. Foo should be a singleton for all object graphs spawned by the Service, but should be a different Foo when spawned by another Object with a different object graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on Scopes in `Dagger-2`.
to make a scope you have just to create an interface like that:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContextScope { // You can call it whatever you want
}
```

and then in your component add the `@ContextScope` annotation.

**Note**: You must clear the instance once you have done from it dagger will not clear it for you. After the Service or Activity is finished, release the instance.

Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/Firebase-Auth-Dagger-2). It implements a UserScope example.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question - could you please advise on how I can define my own scopes in the updated scenarios?

Comment: Define two scope. One for ServiceScope and another ActivityScope, and manage your instances based on that two scopes